# Capybara does not seem to be waiting (as it should do!?) (Async ajax event)

Tags: rspec, capybara

We have a background process that we poll and reload a chart when the processing (from another server, UNIX process) is completed.

I cannot get Capybrara to properly wait (despite the general consensus that it should)

Its an AJAX event that polls the DB and then refreshes the page content when its completed. The timing, even for testing, is varied - a `sleep n.seconds` sometimes works, but not always.

- I have tried `expect(page.has_content)`, `assert page.has_text`, `find`, and `has_content`.
  None seem to actually wait.
- I have timeout set to 90 seconds. Generally the background process is more than 20 seconds.
- I have tried different `default_wait_time`

I have found lots of articles claiming that it should wait within its default polling / time-out. Is there something we should be checking? Note we are headless via Poltergeist.

There is no CSS object that changes on the display, its just a string (this is taken from a `puts page.html` to debug the tests)

From this

```
            <div class="bill-summary-strap-line">
              Calculating your bill costs
              <br/>
            </div>
```

To this

```
<div class="bill-summary-strap-line">
                 Calculating finished
              <br/>
            </div>
```

What are we missing?

RSpec code below, really hope someone has some guidance having solved this type of problem.
Cheers
Ben

```
       puts page.html  # test
       #assert page.has_text?('Calculating your bill costs')
       expect(page).to have_content 'Calculating your bill costs'
       page.driver.render("#{LOGDIR}/output1.png", :full => true)
       sleep 30.seconds  # would like to remove this
       puts page.html # test output
       #page.should have_content("Calculating finished")
       #expect(page.has_content? "Calculating finished").to be_true
       assert page.has_text?("Calculating finished") 
       page.driver.render("#{LOGDIR}/output2.png", :full => true)
```

Comment: Can you explain how the test fails? You say that Capybara doesn't wait; does that mean that your test finished immediately?

Comment: Hi Shepmaster. when i mean doesn't wait i mean that it fails as the string is not in the web page. IF I insert a sleep the string will eventually appear e.g. if you run the app out side of test environment it is working. But to test it the only way seems to be to insert a sleep. However I assumed that if Capybara is meant to wait it would wait within its default wait time to see if the string appears. it does not seem to do that? Make sense?

Comment: Could you add `puts Capybara.default_wait_time` directly before your `assert page.has_text?("Calculating finished")`? I would like to rule out something else changing your timeout under your nose. Also, how long does the test take to fail? It should be taking 90 seconds. Have you enabled Selenium for this test, as opposed to using rack-test? This often appears as `it "does something", js: true do`.

Comment: thanks again. sorry for the delay i've been off rather ill. back at it. didn't think to try this. getting somewhere: the wait time is "2" ... not sure why. spec_helper has it at 30. there are no other includes that change that value. fyi i'm using poltergeist (have issues getting firefox to open on my mac and developers using linux, poltergeist seems consistent, and is quicker)

Comment: i also when through my entire project dir to check nothing updating default waiting time.  nothing (apart from gem spec tests) sets the value

Comment: 2 is the default wait time, so I might guess that something is preventing the original setting of the time. Can you add your `spec_helper` to the question? You could also try overriding the implementation of `default_wait_time=` to print out the stacktrace of all callers, just in case something is resetting it in some strange way.

Comment: ah ok. spec_helper: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=gPNfnqgi (alas you're comment: you could also try overriding the implementation of default_wait_time) i'm not a ruby coder (just trying to manage some awkward team members). so unsure how to do this?

Comment: i just added Capybara.default_wait_time = 30 as a separate line to spec_helper and it works! not sure why Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  #Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {debug: true, :timeout => 90})
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {debug: false, :default_wait_time => 30, :timeout => 90})
end doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `spec_helper`, you have the following code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {debug: false, :default_wait_time => 30, :timeout => 90})
end
```

My guess is that this timeout is basically ignored, as Capybara itself will set the timeout based on `Capybara.default_wait_time`. This would explain why your time was set to 2 inside the spec.

The [poltergeist docs](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) suggest just using this in your `spec_helper`:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

You shouldn't need to register or reregister the driver.

Comment: thanks all - it does seem that the register driver was not working now. should have thought to debug the settings during the tests

Answer (score 0):

Gabe Berke-Williams wrote an article about that :)
You can write your own helper to make Capyabara wait for ajax
See http://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara